# Magento add placeholder text to textarea

Tags: jquery, css, magento

Just like the question says, I tried other solutions on here an none are working, I am trying to isolate it using the data-title attribute, which I would like to stay with that method for some other business requirements.

```
var $bkplace = jQuery.noConflict();

    $bkplace(document).onload(function() {
$bkplace('div[data-title="Recipe Ingredients List"] textarea').attr("placeholder", "test placeholder");
    };
```

Comment: are you sure that element exists?

Comment: Yes, I am using it for something else as well